# How to change FCM push notification icon in web apps

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending FCM notifications through firebase notification manager.But there is no option for notification Icon.So by default its showing chrome.My web app is made using reactjs. How to change that icon?

**This is my firebase-serviceworker file:**

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-messaging.js"
);

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "343676937800",
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDCiXqVCawu6OPsvc87lPWqxoDIZ36RKmQ",
  appId: "1:343676937800:web:ab233c9b1b935ed9439a7d",
  projectId: "fcm-push-notify-bb24d",
});

const initMessaging = firebase.messaging();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import firebase from "./firebase";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging
      .requestPermission()
      .then(() => {
        console.log("permission granted");
        return messaging.getToken();
      })
      .then((token) => {
        console.log(token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <h2>Hello World</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundMessageHandler` to handle customized icon set.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/b2f18e87b240868dd45ca141a328f8778b6de612/messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js#L46-L57

Comment: This will show up 2 notifications, because Google FCM automatically shows up one.

Comment: Can we not add an Icon from the sending side? I'm assuming that the reason that 2 notifications pop up, is due to the time it takes to load the icon's url.

Comment: You can probably get rid of duplicates by closing existing service worker notifications before showing new one.

`return self.registration.getNotifications().then((notifications) => {
    notifications.forEach((notification) => {
      notification.close();
    });

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });`